# python socketserver connection timeout

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python socket programming. I am trying to create a simple chat application I am trying to send data from client program to server but in server program while receiving the data I am encountering "timed out"

My client program-

```
import socket
PORT = 3017

def handler(req):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect(("localhost", PORT))
    except socket.error, msg:
        print("error connecting socket")
        s = None
    finally:
        f.close()
    s.settimeout(10.0)
    s.send(req)
    line = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    return line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(1):
        input = raw_input(">")
        resp = handler(input)
        print resp
```

My server program-

```
import socket
import SocketServer

class echo_server(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        timeout_telnet = float(2.0)
        self.connection.settimeout(timeout_telnet)

        data = []
        # Read in all the lines.
        while 1:
            try:
                line = self.rfile.readline()
            except BaseException, e:
                # Timeout.
                print("error", e)
                break
            data.append(line)
            print("data in handle method-\n", data)
            self.wfile.write(("echo data- ".join(data)))
            break

        # Goodbye


def main():
    s = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(("", 3017), echo_server)
    try:
        s.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down.")
        s.socket.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Probably [https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html] would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you need to control messages length when you are using stream-sockets.

What happends there:

Your client sending some data (N bytes).
Your server reading data from socket, but it does not know is your "message" complete or some additional data will be sent.

What can you do?
If you will replace

> self.rfile.readline()

with self.request.recv(10) - your server will read 10 bytes and will send them back. So you can set some message size for messages your server and client will be sending to each other.

Also some usefull info is here:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket

Here is example of simplest chat:

*CLIENT*

```
def handler(req):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("localhost", PORT))
    message = req
    s.send(req)
    print s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
```

*SERVER*

```
def handle(self):
    while True:
        line = self.request.recv(1024)
        if line:
            print("data in handle method-\n", line.strip())
            self.wfile.write(line)
```

But probably you will face some problens later and python documentation can help you with understanding how does it works.

Comment: replaced self.rfile.readline() with self.request.recv(10) still getting same error however if I write self.request.recv() then I receive data max of 10 characters and I get this error **recv() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)** I get it that function needs one argument but what I am not able to understand as soon as I give some arguments why am I getting time out exception

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was that server was waiting for more message to be sent from client which caused timeout. I have found a solution which is working 
In the client program add this line

```
s.shutdown(1)
```

after

```
s.send(req)
```

and in server program replace

```
line = self.rfile.readline()
```

with

```
line = self.request.recv(1024)
```

shutdown(1) tells the server “This client is done sending, but can still receive.”